# Allocation scans in heaps and indexes

Tags: sql-server, performance, index-tuning

I'm trying to comprehend the difference between an allocation scan in a heap and in a B-tree, performance-wise.

Let's say, that we have an Orders table, with a clustered index defined on the OrderDate column.

If we query it like so:
 `SELECT orderid, custid, empid, shipperid, orderdate, filler FROM dbo.Orders;`

The execution plan will consist of a Clustered index scan with "Ordered" property valued "False", which (if I understand correctly) leaves the storage engine with two options on how to perform it:

1. With an index order scan, starting with the first leaf and proceeding in the order of the index
2. With an allocation scan, starting with the first IAM and proceeding in the file order

The question is: Will there be a difference between the second option and the situation when the Orders table is a heap (hence the storage engine can only use an allocation scan)? And if not, is there any advantage in creating indexes on tables, that would mostly be queried without ordering?

Or I just got the whole thing wrong and it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is there any advantage in creating indexes on tables, that would mostly be queried without ordering?

There is if you ever plan to filter or join by predicates that utilize the fields the index covers. For example, if you wanted to only look at `Orders` in the last year for a table that has 10 years of data, and you indexed on `OrderDate`, then the optimizer would potentially be able to seek on the index to read and return the data that's only in the relevant branches of the B-Tree to serve your query, as opposed to reading the entire table, which a Heap would've resulted in.

But if your intentions are always to read the entirety of the data in the table always, and never `UPDATE` or `DELETE` from it based on any predicates either, nor `JOIN` to it, then there'll be negligible difference in whether you create a clustered index on it or not. Though it's not usual someone has this use case for a table other than a staging table.

While it's true that the index orders the data in the B-Tree data structure by the fields specified in the index definition, that's not the only purpose and benefit of it. Because of the structure of a B-Tree (a nonlinear tree with branches as opposed to a linear structure like a Heap) you get `O(log(n))` search time as opposed to `n` search time. So regardless of if your query uses an `ORDER BY` clause, if it needs to search on a predicate for specific values (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses), then most likely a B-Tree will be the faster data structure for the optimizer to search.

Answer (score 1):

An index-order scan also provides key-order guarantees to the query optimizer it can use in selecting potentially more efficient operators later in the plan, for example a stream aggregate instead of a hash aggregate, or a merge join instead of a nested loops join. There are surprisingly many cases where an underlying order guarantee can affect final plan selection, even where the query itself appears not to require ordering.

There is also a start-up cost associated with performing and maintaining an IAM-driven scan, especially if a parallel scan is used. Creating sub-ranges for a co-operative scan is normally cheaper using a b-tree structure than IAM pages. Smaller scans are pretty much always better driven from a b-tree.

The biggest win for IAM scans is driving large read-ahead. If the object of the scan is already largely in memory, or the storage system is already saturated, there is only extra cost involved.

More background and examples in my article, [Allocation Order Scans](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/allocation-order-scans).